# mono-energetic gamma ray mean free path

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, random, physics

I am writing a code about a mono-energetic gamma beam which the dominated interaction is photoelectric absorption, mu=2 cm-1, and i need to generate 50000 random numbers and sample the interaction depth(which I do not know if i did it or not).
I know that the mean free path=mu-1, but I need to find the mean free path from the simulation and from mu and compare them, is what I did right in the code or not?

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mu=(2)
random.seed=()
data = np.random.randn(50000)*10
bins = np.arange(data.min(), data.max()+1e-8, 0.1)
meanfreepath = 1/mu
print(meanfreepath)
plt.hist(data, bins=bins)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You know your algorithm best. How would you assert that your answers are correct? Hint: you can pick known input and output values across a range and assert your code honours those. This is why even simple programs should have functions that can be fed data from the calling application.

Answer (score 1):

Well, interaction depth distribution is [Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) one, not a gaussian.

So code would be

```
lmbda = 2 # cm^-1
beta  = 1.0/lmbda

data = np.random.exponential(scale=beta, size=50000)
mfp = np.mean(data)
print(mfp)

# build histogram
```

More details at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html

Code above produced

```
0.4977168417102998
```

which looks like 2<sup>-1</sup> to me

Comment: Thank you Severin for your comment I really appreciate it.